# RegEx for matching any 2 letters + any 6 numbers in lucene

Tags: regex, elasticsearch, lucene

I'm writing an Exclude filter for Significant Terms aggregation in Elastic Search. I want to exclude from the results any terms matching the pattern (any 2 letters)(any 6 numbers) ie AB123456

I tried:

```
[a-zA-Z]{2}&<0-9>{6}
```

but Kibana gives an error when I try to update my visualization

```
[x_content_parse_exception] [1:72] [significant_terms] exclude doesn't support values of type: START_OBJECT
```

This JavaScript seems to do what I want:

```
([a-zA-Z]{2}\d{6})
```

but I'm struggling to translate it to Lucene

Comment: Why not just use `[a-zA-Z]{2}\d{6}`?

Comment: `[a-zA-Z]{2}[0-9]{6}` should work.

Comment: Checking [docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-regexp-query.html#regexp-syntax) it seems Lucene doesn't support shorthands like `\d`. Use `[0-9]` instead.

Comment: ```[a-zA-Z]{2}[0-9]{6}``` gives the same error

Comment: Then your problem is not the regex.

Comment: I agree. Your comment was very helpful though because it pointed me in the right direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need the "&" here, it tries to find *tokens* that match both [a-z]{2} and <0-9>{2} at the same time, rather than one after the other.

Here is a solution based on my understanding of the problem. It will exclude documents that contain 2 letters followed by 6 numbers:

```
PUT /stackoverflowtest/_doc/1
{
    "value" : "AB123456"
}

PUT /stackoverflowtest/_doc/2
{
    "value" : "AB1234Z"
}

PUT /stackoverflowtest/_doc/3
{
    "value" : "This document has one at the end: AB123456"
}

POST /stackoverflowtest/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must_not": [
        {
          "regexp": {
            "value": "[a-z]{2}<0-9>{6}"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

This returns only one document, the one for value "AB1234Z" which does not have 2 letters followed by 6 numbers for any token.

Comment: I posted my own answer with the full JSON input I used for my visualization, but I'm marking your answer as accepted because it helped me solve the syntax problems that were causing the error message

Answer (score 1):

Here is the full JSON I used to get the outcome I wanted. I'm using the Significant Terms aggregator to pull keywords from the Notes of support tickets. I needed to set a background_filter, and then exclude the text pattern from my original question.

Document structure:

Summary: Name of the error message

Notes: Details of the error, including usernames such as AB123456 which I don't care about.

```
"significant_terms": {
        "field": "notes",
        "size": 10,
        "background_filter": {
          "query_string": {
            "query": "summary: ErrorMessage1* OR ErrorMessage2*",
            "analyze_wildcard": "true"
          }
        },
        "exclude": "[a-zA-Z]{2}[0-9]{6}"
      }
```